# django use of templates views and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-templates

Sorry I couldn't come with a more precise topic title and I must admit I'm still pretty new Django.

I am trying to work with Ajax and templates with splitted views but I can't achieve what I want, one way or another.

My goal is to be able to work with rendered templates and jquery hide/show instructions but I'm failing at some point.

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views, inventory

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^inventory', inventory.inventory, name='inventory'),
    url(r'^buildInventory', inventory.buildInventory, name='buildInventory'),        
]
```

My views index renders a templated "index.html" (there is a context that I removed for the illustration):

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context)
```

My index.html file :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block delivery_form %}
    <div id="mainblock">
    ....
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And my base.html mostly contains my statics & headers:

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://web-iec/favicon.ico"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'myapp/css/nice.css' %}">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'myapp/js/jquery.js' %}" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'myapp/js/jquery-ui.js' %}" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'myapp/js/inventory.js' %}" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'myapp/js/homepage.js' %}" ></script>
        </head>
        <body>       
        <div class="navBar">
            <span class="navBtn" id="listDeplVer" title="Inventory">Inventory</span>
        </div>    
        <div style="min-height: 100%;margin-bottom: -20px;">
            {% block delivery_form %}    
            {% endblock %}

            {% block inventory %}    
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Now what I'm trying to achieve, within my inventory.js I've got an onclick event that I'm trying to use to hide the home page content and replace it by the rendered html from my inventory.py view with associated html:

my inventory.py:

```
def inventory(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/inventory.html')
```

and my inventory.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block inventory %}
<div id="inventoryblock">
    // html
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Finally my inventory.js is looking like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#listDeplVer" ).click( function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: '/myapp/inventory',
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#mainblock").fadeOut();
            },
            success : function(output){
                $("#inventoryblock").html(output);
            },
        });
});
```

So like I said I was expecting that onclick my page's content is replaced by the rendered inventory page, but this is not working.

When using the web developper tools, if I open the XHR request for the inventory in a new tab it work just fine, so I assume I'm doing something the wrong way.

Before merging everything in one single file (js, views, html & so on) I wanted to ask if there is way to have something similar to work ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source page doesn't have an "inventoryblock" div. That's only in the page you're loading via Ajax. So when your success function runs, it doesn't know where to put the output.

You need to put an empty div with id "inventoryblock" in your index.html.

Also, your inventory.html probably shouldn't inherit from anything. You don't need the full HTML file with the head block etc, you just want the fragment containing the contents of inventoryblock that you can insert into the requesting page. Remove everything other than the relevant HTML itself.

Comment: Hello Daniel, Well in the end I think there was no obvious other way so I proceed as you suggested, meaning merging everything in my index.html so that all DOM elements are present and the javascript can run. After several tries I think at some point the render was preventing the javascript to run, so I ended putting back my html div in the main page and it works. I wasn't able to work the way I intended with the templates but at first it is best to have something working. Thanks!